# Module not found using python27

Tags: python, module

I have the following project files :

[image]

And when I execute the following command :

```
python ./lns/scripts/try_out.py 1 ./lns/data/Example_Instance.txt 1 720007 10 0.08 0.78 0.35 True True False False True ./output_%d
.txt ./solution_%d.txt
```

I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lns/scripts/try_out.py", line 15, in <module>
    from lns.utils import input_output_helper
ImportError: No module named lns.utils
```

I looked for the soution but I  failed to solve it, if you have any idea please help me.

I'm using `python27`

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: I get the project from github and they required Python27